# Create function in postgresql return big table - issue put null to column

Tags: postgresql

I'm new with postgresql.

I'm traying create function with returm big table but when but when I try to insert null in the field it returns an error:

`ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type DETAIL:  Returned type text does not match expected type boolean in column 4.`

This is the first version of the function but it will be expanded / developed on an ongoing basis. Therefore, it is important that it immediately returns all the necessary fields so that it can be called from the software.

I do not know where the error is, whether in the declaration or in the call and what causes it, or do you need to define the field as null somehow?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_letters(
    date_from                 DATE, 
    date_to                 DATE, 
    SystemState_ACTIVE             VARCHAR(50) default 'ACTIVE',
    SystemState_DELETED            VARCHAR(50) default 'DELETED',
    SystemState_INACTIVE           VARCHAR(50) default 'INACTIVE',
    LetterSource_PAPER             VARCHAR(50) default 'PAPER', 
    LetterSource_ELECTRONIC         VARCHAR(50) default 'ELECTRONIC', 
    LetterState_PRINTED           VARCHAR(50) default 'PRINTED', 
    LetterState_IN_TRASH           VARCHAR(50) default 'IN_TRASH', 
    LetterState_REALIZED           VARCHAR(50) default 'REALIZED', 
    LetterState_SENT             VARCHAR(50) default 'SENT', 
    Type_LETTER               VARCHAR(50) default 'LETTER', 
    Type_MOVE_TO_TRASH             VARCHAR(50) default 'MOVED_TO_TRASH', 
    Number_From               INT     default null, 
    Number_To                 INT     default null, 
    Param1_Id                 BIGINT     default null, 
    Param2_Id                 BIGINT     default null, 
    Param3_Number               VARCHAR(50)  default null, 
    Param4_Number               VARCHAR(50)  default null, 
    Param5                   VARCHAR(50)  default null, 
    Param6_Id                  VARCHAR(50)  default null, 
    Param7_Number               VARCHAR(50)  default null, 
    Param8_Number               VARCHAR(50)  default null, 
    Param9                   BOOLEAN   default null, 
    Param10                 BOOLEAN   default null, 
    Param11                 VARCHAR(50)  default null)
  RETURNS TABLE (
    Id             BIGINT,
    Number           VARCHAR(50),
    state           VARCHAR(50),
    col1           BOOLEAN,
    source           VARCHAR(50),
    type           VARCHAR(50),
    fullDate        DATE,
    officeDate         DATE,
    col2Date         DATE,
    col3Date         DATE,
    col4           BOOLEAN,
    col5Number         VARCHAR(50),
    col6InputNumber     VARCHAR(50),
    col7Date         DATE,
    col8           TEXT,
    col9Date         DATE,
    col10           BOOLEAN,
    frozen           BOOLEAN,
    col11           BOOLEAN,
    col12           BOOLEAN,
    col13           TEXT,
    col14           VARCHAR(150),
    col15           VARCHAR(150),
    col16           VARCHAR(150),
    col17           VARCHAR(150),
    col18           VARCHAR(150),
    col19           VARCHAR(150),
    col20           VARCHAR(150),
    col21           VARCHAR(150),
    col22           BIGINT,
    col23            VARCHAR(150),
    col24           VARCHAR(150),
    col25imestamp       timestamp without time zone, 
    col26           BIGINT,
    col27           VARCHAR(50),
    col28           TEXT,
        col29Count         BIGINT,
    col30Count         BIGINT,
        col31Count         BIGINT,
        col32Read         BIGINT,
        col33Count         BIGINT,
        col34Count         BIGINT,
        col35          BIGINT,
        --0l,          --new column soon
    col36           BIGINT,
    col37           BIGINT
  )
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $$
BEGIN 
  RETURN QUERY SELECT 
    l.id letterId,
    l.case_number AS caseNumber,
    L.state AS state,
    null AS col1,
    l.source AS source,
    l.type AS type,
    l.full_date AS fullDate,
    l.office_date  AS officeDate,
    null  AS col2Date,
    null  AS col3Date,
    null  AS col4,
    null  AS col5Number,
    null AS col6InputNumber,
    null AS col7Date,
    null AS col8,
    null AS col9Date,
    null AS col10,
    null AS frozen,
    null AS col11,
    null AS col12,
    null AS col13,
    null AS col14,
    null AS col15,
    null AS col16,
    null AS col17,
    null AS col18,
    null AS col19,
    null AS col20,
    null AS col21,
    null AS col22,
    null AS col23,
    null AS col24,
    null AS col25imestamp, 
    null AS col26 ,
    null AS col27,
    null AS col28,
        null AS col29Count,
    null AS col30Count,
        null AS col31Count,
        null AS col32Read,
        null AS col33Count,
        null AS col34Count,
        null AS col35,
        --0l,
    null AS col36,
    null AS col37
  FROM LETTER l
  LIMIT 1;
END; $$
```

When I substitute a value, it moves on to the next field and not all fields will always have a value.
I tried to create a table and return the data as an existing table but it's the same.

Comment: Try changing from `null AS col1` to `null::boolean AS col1`. Without an explicit cast to `boolean`, PostgreSQL is assuming that `NULL` has a type of `text`. Similar issues will be encountered with other columns as well.

Comment: This ::boolean work !!!
Thenks for help